# erlang mnesia - illegal record info

Tags: erlang, record, mnesia

I am trying to have a function that ensures the table I need is already created and if not to create it. Here's the sample:

```
ensure_table_exists(Table, MnesiaTables, Nodes) ->
case lists:member(Table, MnesiaTables) of
    true ->
        throw({error, db_might_have_already_been_created});
    false ->
        mnesia:create_table(Table, [{disc_copies, Nodes},
                {attributes, record_info(fields, Table)}]), 
        ok  
end.
```

The issue is that when compiling I get the error: `illegal record info`.
It might have to do that record_info is resolved at compile time or that the second argument to record info should actually be a record that can be retrieved from the source code ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all record related *things* including `record_info/2` are resolved at compile time. This means that record and field names must be known at compile time. This is the reason for the compiler error.

I don't think your function is really too defensive in that what you are doing is signaling a more specific error. It would be another matter if you were to **return** `{error, ...}`.

One last point is that if you mean to raise an exception you should not use `throw/1` but instead use `erlang:error/1`. `throw` is intended for non-local return (caught with a `catch`) while `erlang:error` is intended for raising an exception. In many cases the result may be the same but the actual error value may be misleading (`nocatch`). It is always better the clearer you can show your intention, which in this case is signaling an error.

P.S. Yes, I **know** that `catch` also catches errors/exits as well. This was intentional. In a perfect world maybe `catch` should only catch throws and `try` only errors/exits.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately record_info is not really a function even if it looks like one.

You can verify that by testing the following.  Create a file:

```
 -module(something).
 -record(a, {}).
```

Start the Erlang shell:

```
 > rr(something).
 [a]
 > record_info(fields, a).
 []
 > A = a.
 > record_info(fields, A).
 * 2: illegal record info
```

So my recommendation would be to either use a macro or a specialised function for the record_info part.

To answer your original question.  Use something like:

```
 tables() ->
   [?TABLE_MACRO(tablename),
    ?TABLE_MACRO(tablename2),
    ...].
```

where TABLE_MACRO is something like:

```
 -define(TABLE_MACRO(Table), fun() ->
      mnesia:create_table(Table, [{disc_copies, Nodes},
               {attributes, record_info(fields, Table)}])
      end).
```

and then have a function using something like the below.

```
 [case CreateTable of
   {aborted, {already_exists, _}} -> ok;
   {atomic, ok} -> ok
  end || CreateTable <- tables()].
```

Yuck!  Can be cleaned up quite a bit, but hopefully you understand the general idea.

- Macro instead of variable use.
- Match on both {atomic, ok} and {aborted, {already_exists, _TableName}}

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look to [Ulf Wiger's *exprecs*](http://forum.trapexit.org/viewtopic.php?p=21790).

Reading from the description:

> The module is a parse transform
>   allowing you to export records. The
>   transform adds accessor functions for
>   instantiating, inspecting and
>   modifying records, without having to
>   introduce compile-time dependencies
>   between modules.

Said that, your function sounds a bit *defensive* to me. The following page explains why it's a bad habit to program defensively in Erlang:

http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR11

Comment: I know about the bad habit of programming defensively in Erlang, but I don't understand what this has to do with my function ? I am only trying to make sure that I didn't created the schema already.